# Hide a webpart using a query string parameter?

Tags: kentico

I have two web-parts on a same page template and I would like to hide one one of them using a value coming through my query string parameter.

How can I hide a web-part using a query string parameter in Kentico 8 and above?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am assuming you know how to reach visibility section of the webpart.

[image: Visibility section of the webpart]

Click on the little arrow icon highlighted.

Let's assume the querystring parameter name is **cat** and you want to show it if it's value is "Visible"

So you can do it like this

```
{% if( QueryString.GetValue("cat") = "Visible"  {true}else{false} #%}
```

You can also do it in a reverse way like this

```
**{% if( QueryString.GetValue("cat") != "Visible"  {false}else{true} #%}**
```

**Edit:-**

You can use this to check multiple values for a single clause like this

```
if( QueryString.GetValue("cat") != "Visible" && QueryString.GetValue("cat") != "")
```

You can also use this to combine multiple queries like I did in my case.

```
if( QueryString.GetValue("cat") != "" || QueryString.GetValue("Author") != "" || QueryString.GetValue("tagname") != "") {true}else{false} #%}
```

Of course, you can interchangeably use **"||"** and **"&"** by tweaking your logic.

I hope this is enough to handle to all your cases. Let me know if it works.

Comment: That worked. I believe it Is possible to add multiple clauses in this?

Comment: Thank you Chetan Sharma for your detailed answer and adding image to help me identify how to locate it.